# ionicplatform.ready does not get called on load

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have the below code in my controller:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',[]).controller('comeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal)
{
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
          console.log('platform Ready!');
          $scope.callSomeFunction();
        });
....
```

When I run this on my iOS device (not browser), callSomeFunction never gets called and nothing is printed to the console. Any idea what I am missing here?

Comment: and this works when you run it with `ionic serve` command?

Comment: No. I am testing this on my iOS device.

Answer (score 1):

You have to include $ionicPlatform among the injected parameters of the controller.

Modify the first line as follows:

```
angular.module('starter.controllers',[]).controller('comeCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $ionicPlatform)
```

Comment: I included it and it still doesnt work. I am testing this on my iOS device.

Comment: Can you update the question with your index.html code. Might be an issue with the ordering of JavaScript includes.